# multiple search criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query, but I currently have to enter a value in every parameter for the query to work. Is there a way of making the parameters optional, so that 1 or more values will return a result?

```
SELECT * FROM film
WHERE day LIKE '%day%'
AND month LIKE '%month%'
AND year LIKE '%year%'
```

---

something like

```
 function queryData(year,month,day) 

 declare Y

 if year == nothing
     Y = '%'
 else
     Y = '%' + year + '%'

 declare M

 if month == nothing
     M = '%'
 else
     M = '%' + month + '%'

 declare D

 if day == nothing
     D = '%'
 else
     D = '%' + day + '%'

 return result of :

 SELECT * FROM film
 WHERE day LIKE D
 OR month LIKE M
 OR year LIKE Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create your query dynamically? 
Depending on the parameters you have, append the filters dynamically.

e.g.:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM film";
string paramenters = string.empty;

if(day!= string.empty)
  parameters = " Where day LIKE '%day%'";

if(month != string.empty)
{
  if(parameters != string.empty)
     parameters += "AND month LIKE '%month%'";
  else
     parameters = "WHERE month LIKE '%month%'";
}
```

and so on....

In this case you won't get extra results that you will get with `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM film
WHERE day LIKE '%day%'
OR month LIKE '%month%'
OR year LIKE '%year%'
```

You will still be providing all three parameters, but it won't matter if they are blank or NULL, matches will still return from the ones that aren't blank.

Comment: But this wont give the results required.
day="01" and Month="Jan" will get you 1st of Jan 1st of Feb etc. plus all the days in January

Answer (score 0):

Using OR instead of AND changes the logic of the query. It doesn't make the parameters optional. The way to go is not using the parameters you are not using. I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the default value for every parameter to %, when someone fill a parameter, I would pass %value%

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested, but your query looks like it should work as long as you make sure that the unused parameters are empty strings. e.g.

```
day = ""
month = "dec"
year = "2008"
```

would make your query:

```
SELECT * FROM film
WHERE day LIKE '%%'
AND month LIKE '%dec%'
AND year LIKE '%2008%'
```

`'%%'` should match any string as long as it's not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help folks I ended implementing the following. works a treat

```
if year == nothing
   Y = ''
else
   Y = '%' + year + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for a non-dynamic query, something like this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM film
WHERE (:daysearch is null or day LIKE :daysearch)
AND (:monthsearch is null or month LIKE :monthsearch)
AND (:yearsearch is null or year LIKE :yearsearch)
```

Although, I do wonder if there is a performance hit on the database.